# How to ensure we are using __invoke on property and not __call on main object?

Tags: php, oop

Let's assume we have code like:

```
<?php
class Worker {
  public function __invoke() {
    echo "invoked\n";
  }
}

class Caller {
  public $worker;

  public function __construct($worker) {
    $this->worker = $worker;
  }

  public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    echo "called\n";
  }
}

$c = new Caller(new Worker());
echo $c->worker();
?>
```

The result is `called`. What to do to get `invoked`?

Comment: it looks like you've found a syntactical ambiguity, where it isn't possible for PHP to be clear whether you mean `Caller::__call()` or `Worker::__invoke()`. You mean the latter while PHP is assuming the former.

Comment: @Spudley Yes, I know. Now, I want a way to make myself clear to php. That's what's this question is supposed to be about. Feel free to edit it if I did not made myself clear enough.

Comment: it's fine; it's clear to me. There was a comment previously which is now deleted who obviously didn't get it, so I posted this comment to give clarity to anyone else who might be thinking the same. It's a difficult question though; I've given it a +1, and my attempts at finding a solution for you based around something like `{$c->worker}()` failed.

Comment: Yea, `unexpected {` - tried the same before asking. I think we have interesting academical question about magic precedence here.

Comment: @Mołot IF you really need to write a short `($c->worker)();`, you may want to support https://wiki.php.net/rfc/fcallfcall (call the result of an expression (or function) as a function)

Comment: @Mołot There is nothing magic, the method call rule only preceeds the function call rule in the language parser of PHP

Comment: @bwoebi - at php.net both __call and __invoke are in [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) section. That's what I meant by magic, nothing else.

Comment: @Mołot you misunderstood me (has nothing to do if they're magic or not): method call ($object->method(): checks if method exists, then calls it, else calls the __call method if existing) is superior to function call (some_expression() (with some_expression = everything else, not covered by a method call): checks what the type is and handles it then to __invoke if necessary)

Comment: @Mołot See in the language parser the ___order___ in which the conditions happen: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#852

Comment: @bwoebi - well I see the order. The question is - what to do when I know it does not suit my current case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem exists also with anonymous functions which work the same. You have a few ways to work around:

1) modify your __call to check is it's a method, if not, invoke the property:

```
if (property_exists($this, $name) && is_object($this->$name) && method_exists($this->$name, "__invoke")) {
    call_user_func_array($this->name, $args);
}
```

2) call `__invoke` directly: `$c->worker->__invoke();`

3) Save the property into a temporary variable:

```
$tempVar = $c->worker;
$tempVar();
```

4) (nearly the same as 3) (source: http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=136336319809565&w=4)

```
${'_'.!$_=$c->worker}();
```

5) Use `call_user_func` or `call_user_func_array`:

```
call_user_func($c->worker);
```

Comment: To the 1st example -- I totally agree, but it means you need to do this in every object that contains (or **can** contain) another invoke-able object.

Comment: Yes... I think the PHP guys should make something like `{$c->worker}()` valid.

Comment: @Voitcus - re `{$c->worker}()` - I've been trying to come up with an answer along those lines, as it seems like it ought to be the right way, but there clearly isn't a way to do it in current PHP syntax.

Comment: Surprisingly, `${'_'.!$_=$c->worker}();` works. Now, if I only knew how.

Comment: @Mołot this is no surprise as ${...} works, but {...} alone not.

Comment: @Voitcus - I guess there is no place to fill bug report and actually expect it to happen? ;)

Comment: @Mołot No, only support the rfcs... (like the fcallfcall rfc)

Comment: `$a = $this->worker;$result = $this->{$a}();`. Profit. However it looks ugly :/

Comment: @N.B. Wrong. What you are doing, in expanded form is: `$this->{$this->worker}();`. What you may want is `$a = "worker"; $result = $this->{$a}();` what is causing the same issue as we have already

Comment: @Mołot: `$_ = $c->worker` is an obvious assignment. `!$_` negates a truthy value and so evaluates to `false`. `'_'.false` then evaluates to just `'_'` (`false` is coerced to `''`), so in the end you have `${'_'}()` with the difference that in the meantime you managed to do the assignment I mention at the start. The code thus finds and invokes what it "should". It goes without saying that this is ultra horrible and it's only useful for confusing people and/or showing off.

Comment: @Jon exact. I'm just listing it because I've seen it myself and had to think a bit about it. To have it here helps people who may see this at google or so...

Comment: @bwoebi - yes, in expanded form it is what you wrote. However, it's not remotely the same as the thing mentioned previously.

Comment: @bwoebi - I kinda hoped you'd do that after reading my comment, guess I was wrong :) seems I'm as lazy as you to do it

Comment: @N.B. Because it doesn't work... at least when I try to execute it... (echoes called)

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem and it comes that (as you see) it's difficult to tell which object you mean.

The only way (that is "almost" clear) is to use an auxiliary variable

```
$temp = $c->worker;
$temp(); // should be now invoked
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

In case you don't want to implement the __call() Method on all your Callables I'd just extend the Callable like this:

```
<?php
class Worker {
  public function __invoke() {
    echo "invoked\n";
  }
}

class InvokeCaller{

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        if(property_exists($this, $name) && is_object($this->{$name}))
            $this->{$name}->__invoke($arguments);
        else
            echo "called\n";
    }

}

class Caller extends InvokeCaller{
  public $worker;

  public function __construct($worker) {
    $this->worker = $worker;
  }

}

class AnotherCaller extends InvokeCaller{

    public $anotherWorker;

    public function __construct($worker) {
        $this->anotherWorker = $worker;
    }

}

$c = new Caller(new Worker());
$c2 = new AnotherCaller(new Worker());
echo $c->worker();
echo $c2->anotherWorker();
?>
```

**Old**

I came up with this one

```
<?php
class Worker {
  public function __invoke() {
    echo "invoked\n";
  }
}

class Caller {
  public $worker;

  public function __construct($worker) {
    $this->worker = $worker;
  }

  public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    if(property_exists($this, $name) && is_object($this->{$name}))
        $this->{$name}->__invoke($arguments);
    else
        echo "called\n";
  }
}

$c = new Caller(new Worker());
echo $c->worker();
?>
```

We're just modifying our call.

Comment: if you're going to do this, you'd probably be wise to also do an `is_object()` test on the property as well.

Comment: And you don't pass the arguments you've received in your __call?

Answer (score 0):

If [pull request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/301) will be accepted, we will get syntax like:

```
echo ($c->worker)(); //outputs "invoked"
```